# get next line with find command

Tags: cmd

I executed a python file with `cmd` with instruction `'name.py dir'` to get the result.

Now, the result is shown like

```
....
....
processing
....
....
============
result    1   2    3
x.xxx    <---- this is what I want to get
```

I don't want to see the progress, just only want to see the last result, which is the last 2 lines.

so I tried this instruction `'name.py dir | find 'result''`

It obviously found the `result` line, but doesn't show the real result 'x.xxx'.

The result was just,

```
result    1    2   3
```

How can I use `find` instruction to get the next line of `result`?

Comment: @w-cointreau Can try `name.py dir | Select -Last 2` command, Is that working?

Comment: @HiteshSiddhapura it doesn't work, I can't even execute `'select'` instruction. I think there's no select instruction in `cmd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using grep

grep -A 1 result

from man grep:
   -A NUM, --after-context=NUM
              Print NUM  lines  of  trailing  context  after  matching  lines.